# heroku環境で rails appを作成し、awsES にむけて searchkick経由でreindexをかけたが、timeoutになる

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch

heroku環境にて rails app を作成したのですが、searchkick経由でreindexをかけるとtimed outになったためその質問をさせてください。

#### 起きている事象

heroku環境にて searchkick経由で `eroku run rails searchkick:reindex:all` をかけると、以下のエラーが発生する。
こちらのエラーについて調べても情報が出てきませんでした。

```
Error: timed out
    at TLSSocket.<anonymous> (/usr/local/Cellar/heroku/7.47.12/lib/client/7.54.1/node_modules/@heroku-cli/plugin-run/lib/lib/dyno.js:139:29)
```

**環境:**

heroku (hobby)
rails 6.0
searchkickを利用
aws elasticsearch (t3.small.elasticsearch)

ちなみに、indexしたいドキュメントの数は16000ほどです。

これは、おそらくherokuのdynoのメモリー不足が起因しているんでしょうか？
よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1):

自己解決しました。

```
rails runner "Movie.reindex(resume: true)"
```

上記のコマンドでいけました。
停止した場合、再開するという `resume true` が必要だったみたいです。